# How to use full text search and sort them in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I use mongodb, and mongoose to connect from nodejs.
My keywords collection:

```
keywords
{
  _id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId  },
  word: { type: String, index: true },
  rank: {type: Number}, // Rank is count of voting from users.
  source: {type: String},
  link: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Content'} // Link to contents collection
}
```

And contents collection

```
{
  _id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId  },
  title: { type: String },
  content: { type: String }
}
```

My idea:

1. Step 1: use the full text search to find the matching keywords, sort by
   the closest match, rank (group by the same closest match)
2. Step 2: Get links (link property of keywords) to find contents $in
   links.

But its not exactly when sorting at Step 1.

My code:

```
// Get keywords
let indexes = await Keyword.aggregate([
  { $match: {
  $text: { $search: 'request query' }
}},
  { $limit: 100 },
  { $sort: { rank: -1, createdAt: -1 } }, // I want to sort by highest rank
  { $group: { _id: '$link' } },
  { $project: { link: 1 } }
]);

return await Content.find({
  _id: {
    $in: indexes.map((item) => {
      return item._id;
    })
  }
});
```

Any idea to help me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

why not use a single collection?  set the same fields as indexes.  a query on index key words will just look at the index to select docs - it does not open docs as part of the search.  an index exists separately outside the doc.

it kind of looks like you are implementing a split into 2 collections for index searching reasons but Mongodb is doing it for you internally by designating a field as in index.....

Comment: Because the keywords will be added by user. When user type on search box the text, My app will ask user, Is this result correctly with your question?, when user click "YES" then check if exists this keyword in keywords collections then increase rank else it will be saved to keywords collection with rank is 1

Answer (score 0):

the keyword design, and having that field indexed, is a very good idea and will be very efficient.  There is no need to have this field in a separate doc, the index takes care of that.... put the keyword field into the doc of their data as they enter and keep it all together if possible.

Comment: Yes, I know that, But by some reasons, I have to use keyword more open in the future